# How to convert encoded unicode string to native string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

How do I convert a string that looks like the following:

```
s1 = u'MDcxNTFjZWU5MzQ2MTRjZmZiOWIyNTBhYjJlZDhkODY0OTEyYmE2Yjp7ImFjdHVhbF9jcmVhdGVkX3RpbWVzdGFtcCI6ICIxNjcyNDg5NjAxLjMyOTg5MyIsICJhY3R1YWxfaWQiOiAiYWhGa1pYWi1ibWxuYUhSc2IyOXdMVzVsZDNJakN4SWJibWxuYUhSc2IyOXdYMUpsYzJWeWRtRjBhVzl1UVdOMGRXRnNHTUc3QVF3In0%3D'
```

to a string that looks like this

```
s2 = u'MDcxNTFjZWU5MzQ2MTRjZmZiOWIyNTBhYjJlZDhkODY0OTEyYmE2Yjp7ImFjdHVhbF9jcmVhdGVkX3RpbWVzdGFtcCI6ICIxNjcyNDg5NjAxLjMyOTg5MyIsICJhY3R1YWxfaWQiOiAiYWhGa1pYWi1ibWxuYUhSc2IyOXdMVzVsZDNJakN4SWJibWxuYUhSc2IyOXdYMUpsYzJWeWRtRjBhVzl1UVdOMGRXRnNHTUc3QVF3In0='
```

Notice that `s1` ends with `%3D` which is the unicode representation of `=`

I have tried using the `.decode` function but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `%3D` is _not_ the unicode representation of `=`.  That is called url escaping.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't about Unicode encoding (a "Unicode string" is the same thing as a "native string" in modern Python; what you're thinking of is `bytes` vs `str`), it's about URL encoding.  Use `urllib.parse.unquote`:

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> urllib.parse.unquote('MDcxNTFjZWU5MzQ2MTRjZmZiOWIyNTBhYjJlZDhkODY0OTEyYmE2Yjp7ImFjdHVhbF9jcmVhdGVkX3RpbWVzdGFtcCI6ICIxNjcyNDg5NjAxLjMyOTg5MyIsICJhY3R1YWxfaWQiOiAiYWhGa1pYWi1ibWxuYUhSc2IyOXdMVzVsZDNJakN4SWJibWxuYUhSc2IyOXdYMUpsYzJWeWRtRjBhVzl1UVdOMGRXRnNHTUc3QVF3In0%3D')
'MDcxNTFjZWU5MzQ2MTRjZmZiOWIyNTBhYjJlZDhkODY0OTEyYmE2Yjp7ImFjdHVhbF9jcmVhdGVkX3RpbWVzdGFtcCI6ICIxNjcyNDg5NjAxLjMyOTg5MyIsICJhY3R1YWxfaWQiOiAiYWhGa1pYWi1ibWxuYUhSc2IyOXdMVzVsZDNJakN4SWJibWxuYUhSc2IyOXdYMUpsYzJWeWRtRjBhVzl1UVdOMGRXRnNHTUc3QVF3In0='
```